# Почему выдаёт ошибку ??? Error using ==> mtimes Inner matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab

Код:

```
clc
clear
w=@(a)SQRT((9.8*(cos(a*pi/180)-0.1*sin(a*pi/180)))/(25*tan(a*pi/180)* 
(sin(a*pi/180)+0.1*cos(a*pi/180))))*60/2*pi;
x=0:5:20;
y=w(x);
plot(x,y,'b'); 
hold on;
xlabel('a'); 
ylabel('w(a)'); 
grid on;
```

Хочу построить график, но выдаёт ошибку:

```
 ??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==>
@(a)SQRT((9.8*(cos(a*pi/180)-0.1*sin(a*pi/180)))/(25*tan(a*pi/180)*(sin(a*pi/180)+0.1*cos(a*pi/180))))*60/2*pi


Error in ==> lb23 at 5
y=w(x);
```

Как исправить, подскажите пожалуйста.